# Utilizando outro caminho para puxar os arquivos de uma pasta fora o DirectoryInfo

Tags: c#, diretório

Meu projeto está rodando perfeitamente, mas eu gostaria de substituir esse caminho `DirectoryInfo` para um outro que puxa-se direto da pasta sem precisar usar o meu diretório.

Código:

```
public List<Arquivos> GetArquivos()
{

    List<Arquivos> lstArquivos = new List<Arquivos>();
    //DirectoryInfo dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/Arquivos"));
    DirectoryInfo dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo("C:/Users/Usuario/source/repos/FEESC/FEESC/UploadedFiles");
    int i = 0;
    foreach (var item in dirInfo.GetFiles())
    {
        lstArquivos.Add(new Arquivos()
        {
            arquivoID = i + 1,
            arquivoNome = item.Name,
            arquivoCaminho = dirInfo.FullName + @"\" + item.Name
        });
        i = i + 1;
    }
    return lstArquivos;
}
```

Comment: "puxasse direto da pasta" q pasta ? isso é web ou winforms ?

Comment: É ASP.NET MVC mas eu não quero ter que usar todo o diretório queria fazer um ~/UploadFile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tente assim:

`System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Arquivos/");`

```
DirectoryInfo dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Arquivos/"));
```

Comment: sim exatamente isso, muito obrigado